# Keep uploading date 12/30/1899 from excel instead of 1/1/1979

Tags: java, excel

I've inserted data into a *xlsx Excel* file using *selenium* - *Java* automation script. Used '*apache poi*' and uploaded the same file into an application.

But after uploading the '**date values**' uploaded wrongly, always shows **'12/30/1899**' instead of original values from *Excel* sheet. All remaining data from sheet is uploaded correct.

Here is the code, I used to insert data into *xlsx excel* file:

```
    try{
         File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\8024_Dependent_Export(4).xlsx");
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
         XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
         XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
         int rownum = mySheet.getLastRowNum();
         int noOfColumns = mySheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
         int rowcount=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < rownum; i++) {
             rowcount++;
             Row row1 = mySheet.getRow(i);
             if(row1!=null)
             {
                 Cell cell1 = row1.getCell(1);
                 if(cell1!=null)
               if(cell1.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("EE Ref"))
               {
               break;  
               }
             }
         }

         for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
             Cell cell;
              int temp = 0;
             Row row = mySheet.createRow(rowcount+i);
             String[]arr=strings[i];
             for(int j=0;j<14-3;j++){

                 if(j==0||j==3||j==7)
                    continue;
                 for (int j2 = temp; j2 < arr.length; j2++) {

                     if(j==10){
                         CellStyle cellStyle = myWorkBook.createCellStyle();
                         CreationHelper createHelper = myWorkBook.getCreationHelper();
                         cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("m/d/yyyy"));
                          cell = row.createCell(j);
                         cell.setCellValue(arr[j2]);
                         cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                     }else{
                     cell = row.createCell(j);
                     cell.setCellValue(arr[j2].toString());

                     }
                     temp++;
                     break;
                }
        }
         }       
         FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\8024_Dependent_Export(4).xlsx");
         myWorkBook.write(os);
         os.close();
```

**Note**: When manually inserting data and uploading, it's working fine. Only problem when Automation script inserting data into *excel* sheet and uploading.

Please suggest the way needed to insert date cells.

Answer (score 1):

Got the Solution:-

Darkwing, thanks for your suggestion, but no luck

Finally, resolved this isseu by converting date to number, to do this open excel sheet and enter required date into a cell, then select the same cell click Ctrl+1 to open the Format Cells window and switch to the General tab, where you can find the number reffered to a date given in excel.

At end, My automation script entered '28856' this number into excel and uploaded file, then '28856' number represents date '01/01/1979' is shown in application correct

Here is the sample code-

// Creating cell

cell = row.createCell(j);

// set the value '28856' which represents '01/01/1979' date, like give your
     required number (after converting from date to number)

cell.setCellValue("28856");

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to convert your variable to Date:

```
cell.setCellValue(new Date(arr[j2]));
```